# I don't understand why these variables have these values

Tags: python, python-3.x, variable-assignment

I have the following python function but I am confused about line number 2 (q, r = 0, n)

```
1 def div3(n):
2     q, r = 0, n
3     while r >= 3:
4         q, r = q+1, r-3
5     return q

div3(6)
```

If I run the function when the second line executes I get r=6, n=6, and q=0, why is this?
I thought that when the function is first run that upon execution of the second line the values would be r=0 and q=6 and n=6? Does it have to do with the way q r and n are separated with commas?

Comment: python will assign `0` to `q` and value of `n` to `r`. It uses values on the right to assign to variables on the left.

Comment: https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-multi-variables-values/#:~:text=Top-,Multiple%20assignment%20in%20Python%3A%20Assign%20multiple%20values%20or,same%20value%20to%20multiple%20variables&text=In%20Python%2C%20use%20the%20%3D%20operator%20to%20assign%20values%20to%20variables.&text=You%20can%20assign%20values%20to%20multiple%20variables%20on%20one%20line.

Comment: To understand it better, look the expression from left to right. Left most variable before equals will be assigned to the left most after the equal sign.

Comment: Ohhh thank you, I understand now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `q, r = 0, n` line actually uses tuple unpacking. With parentheses, the line would look like `(q, r) = (0, n)`, not `q, (r = 0), n`. Basically, it creates the tuple `(0, n)`, assigns the first element to `q`, and the second to `r`, so the code is equivalent to:

```py
q = 0
r = n
```